# Google mobile friendly test shows page is partially loaded

Tags: web, mobile, wordpress-theming

Whenever i test site url in google mobile friendly test tool, it showing page is partially loaded. I tried to reduce page resources but it still shows this message. Anyone know how to solve this issue.

Comment: I voted to close this question because the topic is too broad to cover in a few paragraphs here. A full answer would require many pages or even an entire book. Please [edit] your question to include enough debugging details that it can be answered.   Once you have done that, please re-ask it at [webmasters.se].  It is not on-topic here because it is not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many questions asked regarding this issue. But no one can give perfect answer. Mobile friendliness is google, bing's ranking factor. Mobile friendly test shows us how actually googlebot or bingbot see our web page. Sometimes it shows "all resources in page is not loaded". May be because google set crawl budget limit on Your site. You can follow this official guide on it "[Mobile Friendly tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6352293?hl=en)"
Try this to solve page resources related issues - Use Faster Loading and responsive themes like Generatepress, Astra. Keep Page Resources under 14 while 25 also fine. Use caching plugins. Make sure you have minify and combine Javascript and css. After minify check manually page is looking good or not. because sometime combining css, styleshit can break your site. In my case, minify and combining css, javascript solved page resources not loading problem.